# Create pandas column of pd.date_range

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[dt.datetime(2018,8,25), dt.datetime(2018,7,21)],
                   'n':[10,7]})
```

I would like to create a third column which contains a date range created by pd.date_range, using 'date' as the start date and 'n' as the number of periods.
So the first entry should be:

```
pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2018,8,25), periods=10, freq='d')
```

(I have a list of "target" dates, and my goal is to check whether the date_range contains any of those target dates).

I tried this:

```
df['date_range'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['date'],
                                                     x['n'],
                                                     freq='d'))
```

But this gives a KeyError: ('date', 'occurred at index date')

Any idea on how to do this without using a for loop, or is there a better solution altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem without creating date range or day columns. To check if a target date in tgt belongs to a date range specified by rows of df, you can calculate the end of date range, and then check if each date in tgt falls in between the start and end of a time interval. The code below implements this, and produces "target_date" column identical to the one in your own answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[dt.datetime(2018,8,25), dt.datetime(2018,7,21)],
               'n':[10,7]})

df["daterange_end"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["date"] + pd.Timedelta(days=x["n"]), axis=1)

tgt = [dt.datetime(2018,8,26)]

df['target_date'] = 0
df.loc[(tgt[0] > df.date) &(tgt[0] < df.daterange_end),"target_date"] = 1

print(df)

#       date         n  daterange_end   target_date
# 0 2018-08-25  10  2018-09-04      1
# 1 2018-07-21  7   2018-07-28      0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `axis=1` in `apply`

```
df['date_range'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['date'], x['n'], freq='d'), axis=1)
```

Comment: This raises ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: Also you need to add "start=" and "periods=" in pd.date_range(), along with axis=1 in apply(), like this:

    df['date_range'] = df.apply(
        lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x['date'], periods=x['n'], freq='d'),
        axis=1
    )

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that works (but I'm sure there's a nicer way...)

```
# define target
tgt = [dt.datetime(2018,8,26)]

# find max n
max_n = max(df['n'])

# create that many columns and increment the day
for i in range(max_n):
    df['date_{}'.format(i)] = df['date'] + dt.timedelta(days=i)

new_cols = ['date_{}'.format(n) for n in range(max_n)]

# check each one and replace with a 1 if it matches the "tgt"
df['target_date'] = 0
for col in new_cols:
    df['target_date'] = np.where(df[col].isin(tgt),
                          1,
                          df['target_date'])

# drop intermediate cols
df = df[[i for i in df.columns if not i in new_cols]]
```